# Invalid_request OAuth2 Google?

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have get code: `4/sfPsZXlH-eO4kqj8EE8WDO70jEMn3HyMuk7ZvjkqL-Q#`.

After try to get access token doing request on url:

```
$authUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri' => getRedirectUri(),
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL => $authUrl,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));
```

But get error:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(15) "invalid_request"
}
```

How can I detect what is wrong?

Comment: can you show us the output of your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? should be all on the same line and separated with & and no html encodeing.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: I try to use this library: `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client`, but dont understand what is `$client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");`?

Comment: from Google developer console when you create you project that's a public api key. It will only work with public data though not private user data.  try looking for a quick start example for your chosen api here is one for analytics api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php

Answer (score 0):

try to print the request for the above.But i cannot see the AuthCode being passed to the token url for getting the access token.You can verify the above process on 
google oauth playground too.
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/